# I want to make the buttons of the phone at the bottom of the application floating and disappearing

Tags: flutter, dart

SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky,); I can do it using this, but a different problem arises.(status bar) icons disappear as seen in the picture. How can I do both at the same time?I tried setting it manually( SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);) and I encountered the same problem again.In short, I want the bottom part to become visible when you pull it and disappear after a few seconds, while I want the top part to remain as shown as ticked in the picture.

[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57TEQ.jpg)

[appears when I drag it up, then disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6sYK.jpg)